Is argocd able to fetch a dependency from my helm repo in artifactory?
Currently, we follow a pattern where each service repo has a folder called "Deploy".
This folder contains a Chart.yaml file, a values.yaml file, and env-values files.
In our pipeline we normally do a helm dependency update and it will fetch the chart from artifactory since it is specified as a dependency in the Chart.yaml file.
Now we are doing an experiment to try argocd.
In the application manifest I have specified my service repo and passed in the values files.
I also used argocd cli to add the helm repo.
However, the "App Conditions" in argo shows 1 error.  401, not able to fetch dependency from our artifactory.
IDK if this is possible in argo, but I am not sure how to specify what is missing in the Application manifest.
Should argo just know which helm repo credentials to use since I did a "argocd repo add"
Do I need to specify that repo in the Application yaml?  How do I do this?

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78835057/how-can-i-configure-argocd-to-use-auth-when-pulling-a-helm-subchart-from-a-priva
