How can I configure ArgoCD to use auth when pulling a Helm subchart from a private location (Artifactory)?
I have an ArgoCD application like this:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  destination:
    name: my-cluster
    namespace: my-app-namespace
  sources: 
  - repoURL: 'https://github.com/my-corp/my-app'
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: src/Deployment  # the location of the Chart.yaml + values files 
    helm:
      valueFiles:
      - values.yaml
      - dv-values.yaml

ArgoCD is configured to have GitHub auth saved as a credential template for all repos in the org.
In my-app's repo there is a Chart.yaml that uses dependencies. like this:
apiVersion: v2
name: my-app
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "33"
dependencies:
  - name: my-chart
    version: 2.0.0
    repository: "https://artifactory.my-corp.com/artifactory/helm/"

ArgoCD successfully pulls the helm chart above from GitHub for my-app but then does not pass any authentication on to Artifactory when trying to grab the dependency my-chart
My application fails to pull my-chart and gives this error:
Error: looks like "https://artifactory.my-corp.com/artifactory/helm" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://artifactory.my-corp.com/artifactory/helm/index.yaml : 401 Unauthorized

This is the same exact error as when trying to do the helm repo add command for this private helm repo without passing any auth via --username and --password.
Does anyone know how to pass the helm auth for a Helm dependency to ArgoCD?

According to the documentation, you can configure it with the following Secret declaration:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: argo-helm
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: repository
stringData:
  name: argo
  url: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
  type: helm
  username: my-username
  password: my-password
  tlsClientCertData: ...
  tlsClientCertKey: ...

